# This article claims to prove that all $\zeta(2n+1)$ for integer $n>0$ are irrational. Is it correct?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I recently stumbled upon the following article:

- [A formula for $\zeta$(2n + 1) and a proof of their irrationality](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01352764v3/document)

This article claims to prove that the values of the Riemann Zeta function at all odd positive integers are irrational. Last time I checked, this problem was categorized as "*near to impossible with the current state of number theory*". Naturally, I am a bit skeptic on whether this proof is correct. However, I do not have the time (or more precisely the required skill) to verify the proof by myself.

**Is the proof in the above paper correct**?

Comment: For something so consequential it is a surprisingly short proof, but this would still take at least a full afternoon for a number theorist to check in detail. At least a few will need to do so before we know the proof is sound. Having said that, Apery's proof on the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$ was important enough, so this would be earth-shattering if it turns out to be correct. I myself am tangentially familiar with this area and did my dissertation in analytic number theory, and in a quick scan nothing leaps out as being grossly incorrect.

Comment: Is lemma 3.1 correct? Shouldn't it be an implication only in one direction?

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.03174v4 . The author comments "An erroneous claim of irrationality of all zeta(2n+1) has been withdrawn, with apologies".

Comment: @Adam I wondered about that and thought I was reading it wrong... You're right, not only does the implication only work forwards, I believe there is a 0 missing, as in $0<|p\alpha - q| < \varepsilon$. Otherwise the statement is false, as it works for rationals too.

Re: arXiv, glad that's cleared up. I thought it was strange that it was dated from 2016 and nothing else had been said about it...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you for the link, that clears it up.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown If you transform your comment into an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the comment section, the claim was withdrawn by the author.